# MySQL IF... SELECT statement whilst retaining column headers

Tags: mysql, if-statement

Fumbling in the dark with MySql but it isn't too bad. (I am a coding novice)

I have a massive database that I need to join to another database (in Arc GIS). I originally did some code to get the joining database with headers (necessary for the join) as that surprisingly didn't come as standard when generating sub data sets with MySQL.

As it is still 3 million records I need to wittle the data down. I am originally did this by querying whether it contained part of a grid square reference (but no titles!). So now I'm trying to see if it contains an image number (grid_image) whilst retaining the column headers. So IF it a field contains a certain number SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE.

I'm struggling with the IF though, any help would be greatly appreciated :).

Laura

Code thus far:

```
WHERE geograph_db.image_numbers.column1 = geograph_db.gridimage_geo.gridimage_id 
SELECT 'gridimage_id','nateastings','natnorthings', 'view_direction' 
UNION  
SELECT gridimage_geo.gridimage_id, gridimage_geo.nateastings,  gridimage_geo.natnorthings, gridimage_geo.view_direction
INTO OUTFILE 'geo.csv'  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
FROM geograph_db.gridimage_geo
;
```

Sorry its awful.

Comment: If should be WHERE statement I think, but what is the relationship between the image_numbers and geograph_db tables?

Comment: OK, added a where. It doesn't like it though still. image_numbers is a table within geograph_db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the syntax should be, I think.

```
SELECT 'gridimage_id','nateastings','natnorthings', 'view_direction' 
  UNION  
SELECT gridimage_geo.gridimage_id, gridimage_geo.nateastings,
  gridimage_geo.natnorthings, gridimage_geo.view_direction
INTO OUTFILE 'geo.csv'  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
FROM geograph_db.gridimage_geo, geograph_db.image_numbers
WHERE image_numbers.column1 = gridimage_geo.gridimage_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D. Tried where at the end just before I saw this, but the other alteration I made broke it, yours works ! :D

Comment: The key difference is that the FROM statement needs to inlcude both tables, and the WHERE statement is defining the relationship on them.  JOIN/ON would be the best syntax to learn for doing this going forward though.